# pdfTeX or pdfLaTeX under Windows/Java using Bytestream

Tags: pdftex, windows

I'm doing servlet programming and i was wondering if pdfTeX or pdfLaTeX have some handle for input or output bytestreams under windows. This way I could stream a string right in and stream the output as a PDF response to the client...any ideas?

Comment: As Heiko mentioned in his answer, sometimes we need multiple runs in order to reach a steady state for our `.tex` file, so one run might not be enough. Besides, sometimes we have documents that might take a considerable time to be generated, so we need to pay attention to the session timeout of the servlet container. Personally, I'd try to play with some webservice instead (input: file, output: file), but that's a matter of taste. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

To some degree `pdfTeX` can read standard input. But it is not unusual compile a LaTeX file more than once, e.g. for the table of contents or to get the references right.

As output files (pdf)TeX writes a `.log` file at any case and
the output file is not suitable for streaming, because `pdfTeX` jumps back in the
written output file. (It writes the length of the stream of a PDF stream object in the
dictionary of this object before the stream part.) And LaTeX might want to write auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`, …).

Thus the servlet could read the input stream, writes it in a file in a temporary
directory and call `(pdf)(la)tex` (or whatever TeX compiler/format). Then the `.log` file
needs to be analyzed for `rerun` stuff. Also other programs like `bibtex` or `makeindex` might need to be calling.

Then if the compile runs are finished, the output file can be streamed back and
the temporary directory can be cleaned up.

Comment: It's indeed a nice workflow. `:)`